# match the pattern at the end of a string?

Tags: python, regex

Imagine I have the following strings:

```
['a','b','c_L1', 'c_L2', 'c_L3', 'd', 'e', 'e_L1', 'e_L2']
```

Where the "c" string has important sub-categories (L1, L2, L3).  These indicate special data for our purposes that have been generated in a program based a pre-designated string "L".  In other words, I know that the special entries should have the form:

```
name_Lnumber
```

Knowing that I'm looking for this pattern, and that I am using "L" or more specifically "_L" as my designation of these objects, how could I return a list of entries that meet this condition?  In this case:

```
['c', 'e']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a simple filter:

```
>>> l = ['a','b','c_L1', 'c_L2', 'c_L3', 'd', 'e', 'e_L1', 'e_L2']

>>> filter(lambda x: "_L" in x, l)
['c_L1', 'c_L2', 'c_L3', 'e_L1', 'e_L2']
```

Alternatively, use a list comprehension

```
>>> [s for s in l if "_L" in s]
['c_L1', 'c_L2', 'c_L3', 'e_L1', 'e_L2']
```

Since you need the prefix only, you can just split it:

```
>>> set(s.split("_")[0] for s in l if "_L" in s)
set(['c', 'e'])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the prefix letter only, e.g. ['c', 'e'], not the entires that match the filter.  But ya, at this point it's an easy split()

Comment: I'd recommend x.endswith('_L')

Comment: These don't end with '_L', then end with '_L#' e.g. '_L1' or '_L2'

Comment: I love stack because I ask a question, it gets answer immediately, then in my sourcecode, I put a hyperlink to this thread so I can remember what I did at that particular line of code.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that my example was a bit poor because in reality I have values like ['a_b_L1', 'a_b_L2'], so I had to replace the "_" in your split call with "_L".  I should have put the more general case as my example, but wanted to point this out for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following list comprehension :

```
>>> set(i.split('_')[0] for i in l if '_L' in i)
set(['c', 'e'])
```

Or if you want to match the elements that ends with `_L(digit)` and not something like `_Lm` you can use regex :

```
>>> import re
>>> set(i.split('_')[0] for i in l if re.match(r'.*?_L\d$',i))
set(['c', 'e'])
```

Comment: Thanks guys, both of your answers got to this, so I appreciate the help.